# Encode an array of integers to a short string

Tags: algorithm, compression

**Problem:**

I want to compress an array of non-negative integers of non-fixed length (but it should be 300 to 400), containing mostly 0's, some 1's, a few 2's. Although unlikely, it is also possible to have bigger numbers.

For example, here is an array of 360 elements:

0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,**2**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1,1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,**4**,0,0,0,0,0,0,**3**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,**2**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**5,2**,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1,2,1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.

**Goal:**

The goal is to compress an array like this, into a shortest possible encoding using letters and numbers. Ideally, something like: sd58x7y

**What I've tried:**

I tried to use "delta encoding", and use zeroes to denote any value higher than 1. For example: {0,0,1,0,0,0,**2**,0,1} would be denoted as: 2,3,**0**,1. To decode it, one would read from left to right, and write down "2 zeroes, one, 3 zeroes, one, 0 zeroes, one (this would add to the previous one, and thus have a two), 1 zero, one".

To eliminate the need of delimiters (commas) and thus saves more space, I tried to use only one alphanumerical character to denote delta values of 0 to 35 (using 0 to y), while leaving letter z as "35 PLUS the next character". I think this is called "variable bit" or something like that. For example, if there are 40 zeroes in a row, I'd encode it as "z5".

That's as far as I got... the resultant string is still very long (it would be about 20 characters long in the above example). I would ideally want something like, 8 characters or even shorter. Thanks for your time; any help or inspiration would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the value of the numbers that can appear? Can the value 128975 exist in some position?

Comment: No, the probably of any value greater than 5 appearing is practically impossible. So while 128975 could exist, I would be okay if it did exist, and made the result string 100000 characters long.

Comment: Whether you can compress the data to fit into a "short" string is going to depend very much on how sparse that data is. If your array of 360 items has 360 random values from 0 to 15, it's unlikely you'll be able to compress it to less than 180 bytes.

Comment: How about a list containing 90% 0's, and 10% 1's? I feel there must be some well-known methods that I just don't know about...

Comment: Use LZW to compress then convert to [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to create a readable string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your example contains long runs of zeroes, your first step (which it appears you have already taken) could be to use [run-lenth encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length) (RLE) to compress them.  The output from this step would be a list of integers, starting with a run-length count of zeroes, then alternating between that and the non-zero values.  (a zero-run-length of `0` will indicate successive non-zero values...)

Second, you can encode your integers in a small number of bits, using a class of methods called [universal codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_%28data_compression%29).  These methods generally compress small integers using a smaller number of bits than larger integers, and also provide the ability to encode integers of any size (which is pretty spiffy...).  You can tune the encoding to improve compression based on the exact distribution you expect.

You may also want to look into how [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Entropy_coding)-style encoding works.  After DCT and quantization, the JPEG entropy encoding problem seems similar to yours.

Finally, if you want to go for maximum compression, you might want to look up [arithmetic encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding), which can compress your data arbitrarily close to the statistical minimum entropy.

---

The above links explain how to compress to a stream of raw bits.  In order to convert them to a string of letters and numbers, you will need to add another encoding step, which converts the raw bits to such a string.  As one commenter points out, you may want to look into [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) representation; or (for maximum efficiency with whatever alphabet is available) you could try using arithmetic compression "in reverse".

Additional notes on compression in general:  the "shortest possible encoding" depends greatly on the exact properties of your data source.  Effectively, any given compression technique describes a statistical model of the kind of data it compresses best.

Also, once you set up an encoding based on the kind of data you expect, if you try to use it on data *unlike* the kind you expect, the result may be an expansion, rather than a compression.  You can limit this expansion by providing an alternative, uncompressed format, to be used in such cases...

Comment: Thank you very much for your inspiration! I will look into those topics tonight.

Answer (score 2):

In your data you have:

```
14 1s (3.89% of data)
4 2s (1.11%)
1 3s, 4s and 5s (0.28%)
339 0s (94.17%)
```

Assuming that your numbers are not independent of each other and you do not have any other information, the total entropy of your data is 0.407 bits per number, that is 146.4212 bits overall (18.3 bytes). So it is impossible to encode in 8 bytes.

Comment: If the integers are not statistically independent, he might be able to improve on that...

Comment: @comingstorm I agree. Adding that caveat to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for making me realize my goal might not be achievable. Maybe I should do something before producing an array of 400 integers.